# python get the correct path for a file

Tags: python, paths

I want to write out the path of zipfiles, which are located in "zips" folder. Here is my code :

```
import os, zipfile

directory = 'zips'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".zip"):
        file_name = os.path.abspath(filename)  # get full path of files
        print(file_name)
        continue
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Now it gives an uncorrect answer: 
/home/huhu/PycharmProjects/monitoring/aa.zip
/home/huhu/PycharmProjects/monitoring/bb.zip

And it should be 
/home/huhu/PycharmProjects/monitoring/zips/aa.zip
/home/huhu/PycharmProjects/monitoring/zips/bb.zip
What is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Because the result of `os.listdir(directory)` is the list of names (without a path) of the files in that directory (`['aa.zip','bb.zip']`). When you give them to `os.path.abspath(filename)`, they are considered to be in your current directory, since the `zips` directory isn't mentioned anywhere. You can use instead:

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('zips/*')
```

or even, to avoid filtering:

```
for file in glob.glob('zips/*.zip')
```